Google Drive no longer available after updating to Ubuntu
My system has just updated itself to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
After the update, Google Drive seems to have disappeared from the computer.
I have re-signed-in to my Google account in "Settings > Online Accounts", I even deleted the account and created it again from scratch.
But whatever I do I do not see my Google Drive (email address) in "Files".
How can I get it back?

Just encountered this today.  I upgraded to 24.04 and I have tried deleting and re adding my google account, and the drive shows up in the sidebar in nautilus/files, but I get a permission denied even though I seemed to be logged in properly via my browser.
Edit... there are a bunch of tick boxes in the browser confirmation page... I had to check them all and this was not terribly obvious.  Solved.  it works now.
